# Find string length from select form field with multiple values with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried several methods only to discover that the usual str.length code is not reading the entire form field contents

Html:

```
<select id="states1" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="AL">AL</option>
<option value="AK">AK</option>
<option value="CA">CA</option>
</option>
```

No matter how many states I select, the javascript only reads the first state selected. For example, if I have selected all 3 states, the only validation checks that work are found below:

```
<script> 
var slen = document.forms[0].elements['states1'];
function invoice_() {
if(slen.value == "AL"){
 alert('true');
 return false;
 } }
</script>
```

And to check the length

```
<script> 
var slen = document.forms[0].elements['states1'];
function invoice_() {
if(slen.value.length == 2){
 alert('true');
 return false;
 } }
</script>
```

In other words, even if the actual length of the form field contents is 6, the only way I have found to check the string length in javascript only returns 2, in my example, because it only reads the first selected state but not the others

I have tried

```
slen.value.options.length

slen.options.length
```

To get the right number, but those methods don't work.

How do I get the code to read the entire form field contents to count the length when it is a select multiple option field with multiple options selected?

Comment: The specification can be useful at times https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#dom-select-selectedoptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best solution for someone who might need it:

```
let uvs = document.forms[0].elements['states1'];
function invoice_() {
 var result = [];
  var options = uvs && uvs.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }


var nst = (result.push(opt.value || opt.text)) - 1;
if(nst > 3){
alert('');
return false;
}
```

For some reason the raw count of 'result.push(opt.value || opt.text' is +1, so I just added a little math to make the count accurate. I was initially looking to count the number of characters, but finding the number of states selected was even better. Instead of a result of 10 for 5 states I get 5 for 5 states.

The other character count code above was too unstable. Might be a browser issue, hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.selectedOptions` property to get the selected options in the multiple select. Then convert it to an Array, and do a `.map().reduce()` to total up the values.

```js
var totalLen = Array.from(document.forms[0].states1.selectedOptions)
  .map(v => v.value.length)
  .reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0);

console.log(totalLen);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="states1" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL" selected>AL</option>
    <option value="AK">AK</option>
    <option value="CA" selected>CA</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

---

If you wanted all the options instead of just the selected ones, then use the `.options` property instead.

```js
var totalLen = Array.from(document.forms[0].states1.options)
  .map(v => v.value.length)
  .reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0);

console.log(totalLen);
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="states1" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="AL" selected>AL</option>
    <option value="AK">AK</option>
    <option value="CA" selected>CA</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: If I use `states1.options` the code gives me a length of 100, which is right. However, when I use `states1.selectedOptions`, no matter how many states selected, the code returns 0 for the length

Comment: It may be running before any selections are made?

Comment: The code acts weirdly. If I try fresh, I'll get 0, but if I refresh 2x and select another state I get the right  #.  So, there is something inherently instable with that code. I need something else.

Comment: @cdr1: This code merely reads a list of values. There's nothing unstable about it. It's most likely related to your event handlers or something.

Comment: Actually I read that "selectedOptions" doesn't work well with certain browsers. It dosen't work at all with IE, and apparenly with FF is performs erratically. I found that out the hard way :) Once I changed the code to what I posted below, everything worked smoothly.